# How to automate IE upgrade to latest supported version using any script

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell, batch-file, upgrade

My question is can i upgrade the IE version to the latest supported version on windows server 2008 R2. 
I searched many posts and forums, but didn't get how to automate the IE upgradation task using powershell script or a batch script.
I got powershell command on how to get verify the IE version that is running.

```
(Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer').Version
```

So, do you think if i can download the IE installer file, would i be able to run that executable file from a script (Any script). If yes then how. Need to run it in non interactive mode.

Answer (score 0):

```
$exepath ='c:\install\IE11-Windows6.1-x64-en-us.exe'
$arguments='/quiet norestart'
Start-Process -FilePath $exepath -ArgumentList $arguments -PassThru
```

Download the exe and save it as a file where you want, change the `$exepath` to the correct path. This should work then. `/quiet` makes it "non-interactive"